# Listen to changes on ObservableObject (with Travis CI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, travis-ci, combine

I have a class that conforms to `ObservableObject`, and for testing purposes, I'd like to listen to when the object changes. However, I am getting an issue. Here is the smallest fragment that I am able to reproduce the issue from:

```
import Combine
import XCTest

class FooTests: XCTestCase {
    func testListen() {
        let object = Foo()
        var count = 0
        let sub = object.objectWillChange.sink {
            count += 1
        }     
        object.objectWillChange.send()
        XCTAssertEqual(count, 1)
        sub.cancel()
    }
}

fileprivate final class Foo: ObservableObject {}
```

When I run this test locally, it passes fine. However, it fails when it is run on my CI server (I am using Travis CI) because `count` is `0` rather than `1`. I cannot figure out any reason why the different environments would cause this to happen. Could I be using an incorrect version of Combine, and its behavior has changed? Or could there be some sort of an environment variable that would affect this behavior? Or is there another way to listen to changes on `object` other than doing `object.objectWillChange.sink {}` that will work? I'm at a complete loss to explain it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `objectWillChange` guaranteed not to switch queues/threads? I wonder if that's what's causing it. Your assertion could run before count is incremented.

Comment: @RobN That hadn't occurred to me, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I added a 5 second delay before the assertion, and the issue still remains.

Comment: You could use `DispatchQueue.main.async { XTCAssertEqual(count, 1) }` to guarantee the assert is executed after the `sink`. Do not forget to make sure `sub` is still alive by then (make it a member of the `FooTests` class).